# (QnAMaker) How to assign multiple values to one metadata tag?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have some question data that belongs to multiple categories.

So, I'd like to assign multiple values to one metadata tag below.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mentioning metadata as below structure:
[image]

You can add metadata tag for it to make it right link.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/add-question-metadata-portal#add-metadata-to-filter-the-answers

Comment: What if I have two locations having same set of questions. Can I add `Location : Seattle, Texas` and while using strictFilters for Texas only if I use `"strictFilters": [ { "name": "location", "value": "Texas"}]` does it return all possible matches from the previous question list.

Comment: @Hari Did we found any answer to it? I have the same problem. I am now using custom question answering from Language service.